# Como aplicar uma classe css em um elemento filho de um componente com javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, react

Possuo um componente chamado `<PDFDownloadLink>` que preciso alterar o filho `<a>` que ele possui.

Com css syntaxe eu faria algo como:

```
PDFDownloadLink a {

}
```

Como poderia fazer o semelhante com js?

Meus estilos atualmente são criados com:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    PDFDownloadLink : {
       ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

apenas precisa fazer isso:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    PDFDownloadLink : {
       '& a': {
           ...
       }
    }
)}
```

Espero que eu tenho ajudado.